# report viewer didn't show reports

Tags: asp.net, report, reportviewer, rdlc

I try to view reports in my report viewer but it show nothing

my on load function where the report viewer is 
like :

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Reports/MainReport.rdlc";
DataTable orderDt = controller.SelectFullOrderDetailsInfo(orderID);
ReportDataSource rptds = new ReportDataSource("OrderInfo", orderDt);
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rptds);
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
ReportViewer1.DataBind();
}
```

Report viewer page just run empty and didn't show any thing ! what I'm missing

Comment: Have you check the report path is correct and datasource is not null?

Comment: What browser are you using? There are some compatibility problems.

Comment: @huMptyduMpty,yes I do my report path is Ok and also my datasource have data

Comment: @EmanueleGreco I'm using IE 8

Answer (score 1):

I know my reply is 5 years after the question is asked :), but I put my findings here, hopefully, it will save time for others in the future.

Recently I have done 60 reports for my company. Bellow are causes of a report not showing:

1: Most Frequent case: You report has parameters which can be empty or null. If you have parameters make sure you specify that those parameters can accept empty or null values, otherwise re[rot shows as empty. To verify, remove all parameters from the report and run it without any parameters.

2: Check rptds Table(report DataSource) to make sure it is populated.

3: (This one happened to a couple of times). Browse your code to make sure you do not set the report viewer visibility to false.